# Unusual writing error in fastq file: header move to 4th line i.e. quality score value line

Tags: python, fastq

I have transcriptome sequencing data but there is a problem during sequence writing.

Now the sequencing data looks like this:
[image: Problem in fastq sequence while writing from sequencer]

Normally the data should look like (4 line format):

```
@HWI-1KL133:1:1101:3288:2194#0/1 [header- first line]
CTGCCCAAAAACTCCTTCTTCTCCGAGTTCCAGATGAATTTTTTCCAGCTG [sequence- second line]
+ [ "+" sign - third line]
Y^^]cccRbc^cWY^aacedhXJbPHWP_^ca^[^Ia^XacIY_R^^cBBB [quality values - fourth line]

@HWI-1KL133:1:1101:3567:2197#0/1
GCAGGGTTTAGGAAGTTGTTCACATTGGGGCTTGGCAGTTGTTGAGAAGGA
+
_b_eeecdgggggiiegiiiihiiiihiiiiiiiiaghgfhhiidhfhhhe
```

But in my case it is looking like this:

```
@HWI-1KL133:1:1101:3288:2194#0/1
CTGCCCAAAAACTCCTTCTTCTCCGAGTTCCAGATGAATTTTTTCCAGCTG
+
Y^^]cccRbc^cWY^aacedhXJbPHWP_^ca^[^Ia^XacIY_R^^cBBB@HWI-1KL133:1:1101:3567:2197#0/1
GCAGGGTTTAGGAAGTTGTTCACATTGGGGCTTGGCAGTTGTTGAGAAGGA
+
_b_eeecdgggggiiegiiiihiiiihiiiiiiiiaghgfhhiidhfhhhe
```

Here, you can see that for the first sequence the format of fastq is maintained but for the second sequence the header line i.e. started with `@HWI-1KL133:1:1101:3567:2197#0/1` was merged with the fourth line of the first sequence.

I want to remove the unusual header from the 4th line and put it into the upcoming header line (1st line of the next or second sequence).

I request you to please provide possible solution.

Comment: The problem is poorly defined: "the problem" you mention is not described. You then ask for a solution for a task which is, in my humble opinion, not precisely described. Please, describe what is you're trying to achieve and add a minimal example with input and expected output.

Comment: @EnricoM.Crisostomo Pardon me for poorly defined problem. I have edited my question. Please have a look on it.

Comment: If the (original) length of the reads is really constant (it seems so) you could construct a sed or awk script to include `'\n'` at the affected places.